# How to transfer an image from a tableView to another imageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I cannot transfer an image and text from a tableView to another imageView using `prepareForSegue` method.

`foodimages` is an array holding `imageNames` of type string.

I have also tried:

```
let imgName = "image\(index).png"
```

but failed.

```
import UIKit

class TableView: UITableViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

var foodNames: [String] = ["Food1","Food2","Food3","Food4","Food5","Food6","Food7","Food8"];
var foodImages: [String] = ["image1", "image2","image3","image4","image5","image6","image7","image8"];


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tblFoto", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = foodNames[indexPath.row]
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: foodImages[indexPath.row])!
    cell.imageView!.image = image

    return cell
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showIMG", sender: indexPath)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if (segue.identifier == "showIMG") {
        var destViewController: imgView = segue.destinationViewController as! imgView

        var index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row

            let imgName = foodImages[index]        //"image\(index).png"
            let data = UIImage(named: imgName)!
            destViewController.photo = data
    }
}
```

**Second Class**
 named "imgView" is

```
import UIKit

class imgView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var secView: UIImageView!
var photo: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    secView.image = photo
}
```

}

In debug area it gives:

> index   (Int)7
>      imgName (String)    "KLWR"
>      data    (UIImage)   0x000000010d667e10  0x000000010d667e10

Comment: Are you sure that the name you are passing here 'UIImage(named: imgName)!' is present in your bundle? as this method 'UIImage(named:' always fetch the image name  from the bundle..

Comment: is `photo` an UIImage as well? how do you detect that the image is in fact *not* transfered?

Comment: Strange thing to me is that after using `deselectRowAtIndexPath`, `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` is still returning a value.

Comment: i do not know what's the matter with this btw 
i have uploaded my complete code, kindly review it
Thank you  Vizllx, luk2302 and flash advanced

Comment: yes, it is returning a value.     @flashadvanced

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening here is that you try to assign the `UIImage` in `viewDidLoad` and it is called before you assign the image in the calling view controller.

What you can do is something like this:

```
var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        self.secView.image = image
    }
}
```

So you expose an image property in the destination view controller and when the image is set then you update your image view.

Comment: it still returns a value in "index" but cannot access an image from "foodImages[ ]"